# Research Effort

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes

What is a research effort (or the lack of it)?

[image]

As seen here - [Imitating a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211538/imitating-a-static-method)

Comment: You seemed to have failed to do any research into what this site considers "research effort" to mean.  It is a *very* frequently discussed topic.

Comment: You could constructively inquire what the commenter means and how you can address his concerns.

Comment: @Damien This isn't a proposal; there isn't anything to disagree with.  It is however a very poorly researched question.  Even on meta, asking a very poorly researched question can get you downvotes.

Comment: @Servy good point, and looking at the question again, it does seem to be not particularly well researched.

Comment: The upvote and downvote links are less than a key apart. Why do users fail to upvote good answers on numerous instances?

Comment: Politics? I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @GLES the 50% that were upvoted, some were upvoted multiple times (8 upvotes on one) - that is very good!

Answer (score 7):

You should always try to find the answer to your question **first by yourself**. Doing this is called *Research effort*.  [This is why we require it.](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

You google and try to find an answer. But in case of your question I would not say that this was a **total** lack of research effort, but you could have found the answer if you put more effort in the research.

Comment: You think his question was well researched?  I...disagree

Comment: I agree with you, but Google results show up Stack Overflow links - so basically this suggests that SO is the new Google :) which is a good thing - right? https://www.google.co.in/search?q=imitate+static+python

Comment: No it was not well researched. But I would not say it was a total lack of research. The user added code and asked if that was the correct way to go.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=appropriate+multiplication

Comment: Putting the question, word for word, that the OP used, brings up, as the first result, a page of the python docs that goes into some detail about the topic.

Comment: [*"so basically this suggests that SO is the new Google :) which is a good thing - right?"*](http://i.imgur.com/toK97bd.gif)

Comment: I wonder why nobody voted-to-close if the case is so clear ;)

Comment: This explains *what,* but not *why.*  I fixed that for you.

Comment: @GLES If So is the new Google we would be a Search Engine...

Answer (score 6):

Googling `static method python` brings up this as the first result:

[Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

which your question is a duplicate of.

There's some room for debate on what constitutes a lack of research effort, but I think it's pretty clear that posting a duplicate of a question which comes up as the first result for the most obvious Google search you could perform constitutes a lack of research effort.

Comment: @GLES Which is relevant how?

Comment: @GLES Wrong how?

Comment: @GLES then answer the older one with a correct answer

Comment: Had enough of Stack Overflow. I'll only use Google now. But I'll still say that "Google this, Google that" is not the reason why Stack Overflow came into being - 1. stackoverflow.com/questions/231767 2. stackoverflow.com/questions/114543 3. stackoverflow.com/questions/60174

Comment: Oh come on @GLES. It's one response, to one question, which was a duplicate. Just improve your questions and move on.

Comment: @GLES The fact that you weren't using Google before now is exactly the *problem*.  Neither is a replacement for the other.  Both augment each other.  If you're not using both, you're doin' it wrong.  You should be using Google, and other resources available to you, to try to find solutions to your problems.  If you fail to find a solution, after extensive research, *then* you ask a question on SO, so that the next person doesn't need to ask, they'll find the results in Google.  You skipped the first (and most important) step.  The community responded properly and downvoted.

Comment: @GLES - FYI, you can find instructions for having your account deleted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Answer (score 2):

*Research effort* is an indication of how much research the questioner performed before asking their question.  Specifically, what have you tried, what you sought out and what you tried again.

Perhaps in your case, you could look up/research Python static methods and write what you did not understand from that research in your question.